# Hibernate Converter + retrieve attributename inside Converter

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, annotations

We are trying to use hibernate Converter to encrypt / decrypt data stored via hibernate for few columns

```
@Convert(attributeName="myattr",converter=DataEncryptionConverter.class)
private String actualValue;
```

The plan is to implement reusable Converter based on data type (String, Date etc).

However the plan is to maintain a config template that indicates if the field encryption should be turned on / off =

Approach

```
@Converter
public class DataEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<String,String>{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataEncryptionConverter.class);
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String arg0) {
        logger.info("convertToDatabase>input:"+arg0);
        if(attributeName matches (TemplateList)) { 
           //check if the attributeName is part of approved TemplateList where data needs to be encrypted
           return encryptData(arg0);
        }
        else {
          return  arg0;
        }
   }
    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String arg0) {
        logger.info("convertToEntity>input:"+arg0);
        if(attributeName matches (TemplateList)) { 
           //check if the attributeName  is part of approved TemplateList where data needs was encrypted
           return deCryptData(arg0);
        }
        else {
          return  arg0;
        }
    }

}
```

So, is there any way to retrieve the attributeName that is set as part of @Converter ?

Comment: did you get your answer ?

Comment: I am also having the same doubt

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for a way to pass params from the entity field to Converter,

I found the **AttributeName** parameter in the **@Convert** class and went to check what it does.

But, to my regret, I found that ****AttributeName** is not intended to transmit data to the **Converter**.**

That is the purpose of **AttributeName**:

From the the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) of **@Convert** class:

The AttributeName element must be specified to an embedded attribute or to a map collection attribute whose key or value is of embeddable type (in which case the converter is applied to the specified attribute of the embeddable instances contained in the collection)

The attributeName element **must not be specified** to a basic attribute or to an element collection of basic type (in which case the converter is applied to the elements of the collection)

**Examples of AttributeName usages:**

Apply a converter to a map key of basic type:

```
 @OneToMany
 @Convert(converter=ResponsibilityCodeConverter.class, 
          attributeName="key")
 Map<String, Employee> responsibilities;
```

Apply a converter to an embeddable attribute:

```
 @Embedded
 @Convert(converter=CountryConverter.class, 
          attributeName="country")
 Address address;
```

Apply a converter to a nested embeddable attribute:

```
 @Embedded
 @Convert(converter=CityConverter.class, 
          attributeName="region.city")
 Address address;
```

Apply a converter to a nested attribute of an embeddable that is a map key
of an element collection:

```
 @Entity public class PropertyRecord {
      ...
     @Convert(attributeName="key.region.city", 
              converter=CityConverter.class)
     @ElementCollection
     Map<Address, PropertyInfo> parcels;
 }
```

Apply a converter to an embeddable that is a map key for a relationship:

```
 @OneToMany
 @Convert(attributeName="key.jobType", 
          converter=ResponsibilityTypeConverter.class)
 Map<Responsibility, Employee> responsibilities;
```

Override conversion mappings for attributes inherited from a mapped superclass:

```
 @Entity
     @Converts({
        @Convert(attributeName="startDate", 
                 converter=DateConverter.class),
        @Convert(attributeName="endDate", 
                 converter=DateConverter.class)})
 public class FullTimeEmployee extends GenericEmployee { ... }
```

I am still looking for a solution how to pass parameters to the Converter, Any idea how to keep using the converter class and send parameters from the converted field to the converter is welcome